# SQL JOIN 2 tables using the search result of one column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables I would like to join as followed:I have players who are part of teams. For one player I would like to check in which team he is playing and to display all details of the team).

```
SELECT id_team 
    FROM team_by_membe
    WHERE id_membre = $id_membre (the team member I want to select)

SELECT name_team, id_organisation, etc
    FROM team
    WHERE id_team= (results of the above table)
```

My issue is that there are many results in the first SELECT. 
Any ideas?

Comment: please show your tables schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid duplications caused by teams with multiple members, you could use the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   team
WHERE  id_team IN (SELECT id_team 
                   FROM   team_by_membe
                   WHERE  id_membre = $id_membre)
```

Comment: Thanks; seems to be a very nice way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
"SELECT t.* FROM team t
INNER JOIN team_by_membe tbm ON tbm.id_team=t.id_team
WHERE tbm.id_membre = ?"
```